# pass multiple defines or const as a parameter to a class method

Tags: php

Can I do something like this?

```
class Test
{
    const FLAG1 = 'flag1.';
    const FLAG2 = 'flag2.';

    public function __construct() {}

    public function myMethod($flags)
    {
        echo $flags
    }
}
```

then use it like

```
$test = new Test();
$test->myMethod(Test::FLAG1|Test::FLAG2);
```

I tried to use this example but I get `2` as my `echo`.
I was just curious to see how I can use either `CONST` or `DEFINE` as parameters to a method.

I ask because I found this script that uses this technique and I found it curious

http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/preg_find.php.txt

Comment: if you remove the bitwise operator `|` and just pass in one flag, that will work.

Comment: yup, but my things was that I wanted to see how this guy did his magic: http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/preg_find.php.txt

Comment: Yes, but he's not passing parameters, he's doing bitwise operations - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but not with the flag values you have now.

Bitwise operators work on... well, the bits.  If I do `1001 OR 0110`, I get `1111`.  Therefore, if you want to be able to use constants like this, their values need to be powers of two.

```
const FLAG1 = '1';
const FLAG2 = '2';
const FLAG3 = '4';
```

You can then test for the method by `AND`-ing the parameter value of your function to a mask.  For example, if someone passes in `FLAG1|FLAG2`, you can test for flag 2:  `0011 AND 0010 = 0010` which is equal to `FLAG2`.  In PHP, this would be `($flags & FLAG2) == FLAG2` to get a boolean of whether or not FLAG2 was passed in

You can see all of the bitwise operators here:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

I should also point out that this would be generally considered poor form for PHP programming.  Why do this when there are far better ways to pass in multiple parameters?  Personally, I'd just accept an array.

Does this make sense?  If not, ask more detailed questions and I will follow up.

Comment: I understand, I usually accept and array as my parameter but I was trying to create something unique and atheistically different. But I would be greatful if you could elaborate a little more on why I need to check `($flags & FLAG2) == FLAG2` can't I just check for `FLAG2`?

Comment: @Eli, No, because `FLAG2`.  When you `AND` `FLAG2` and `$flags` together, you get a value that will be equal to all `0`s, or you will get a value equal to `FLAG2`.  Again, `1 AND 1 = 1`, and `0 AND 1 = 0`.  Basically you use the `AND` operation as a filter, to filter out all of the other flags you may have set that were passed in `$flags` to your function.